# Xamarin Forms (Android): OnCreate bundle is null

Tags: c#, android, f#, xamarin.forms

I have an Android project, and I wish to store my API keys in my Android Manifest file. To read them, I can read the bundle that comes through in the `OnCreate` override in my `MainActivity` class: viz

```
type MainActivity () =
    inherit FormsApplicationActivity()
    static let [<Literal>] MyApiKey = "my-api-key"
    override this.OnCreate (bundle) =
        base.OnCreate(bundle)
        let createViewModel() = new PhotoSetViewModel() :> IRoutableViewModel
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException.AddHandler(UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(AppExceptions.processException))
        Forms.Init(this, bundle)
        Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle)
        // Read the API key that I've stored in AndroidManifest.xml
        let platform = new DroidPlatform(bundle.GetString(MyApiKey)) :> ICustomPlatform
        let app = new App<ICustomPlatform>(platform, new UiContext(this), createViewModel)
        app.Init()
        base.LoadApplication app
```

There is one small problem. `bundle` is always null. This is happening in all of my projects, in both C# and F# implementations.

I'm using the Xamarin.Forms NuGet package, Version 2.3.4.224.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to use the `bundle` argument, it is possible to retrieve the metadata as follows:

```
let metaData = PackageManager.GetApplicationInfo(PackageName, PackageInfoFlags.MetaData).MetaData
let platform = new DroidPlatform(metaData.GetString(MyApiKey)) :> ICustomPlatform
```